# Errors after creating a new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Just now I updated my android studio from build 130.737825 to build 130.878379. When I create a project for the first time, I am getting following error.

```
Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':MyApplicationadfaldf'.
    > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
       > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':MyApplicationadfaldf:_DebugCompile'.
          > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+.
            Required by:
                MyApplicationadfaldfProject:MyApplicationadfaldf:unspecified
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For others, who may be facing the same problem, 
Go to Tools-> Android-> SDK Manager, and update all repositories. Now, everything will work properly.

Comment: you should set this to answered

Comment: @samael I can set after 2 days..:)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue in my project was fixed with this:

In Android Studio:

```
-> Go to File menu -> Settings -> Gradle ->
```

Now in **Gradle Settings** just check **Use Auto-Import** Now update Maven will be updated in Android Studio and this error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

http://tools.android.com/knownissues#TOC-Bundled-Maven-Repository

you need to install "android support repository"